# Sinatra activerecord initialize

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I got a strange situation.Could somebody give me advise ?
I am developing an App with

```
Ruby1.8.7
Sinatra 1.4.4
Activerecord 3.2.14
Mysql 5.6.19
```

I almost finish developing but at the last moment I got stack.
I have two tables in MySQL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE items(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  type text,
  keyword text,
  postid INT,
  created_at datetime NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE comments(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  comment text,
  yourname INT,
  postid INT,
  created_at datetime NOT
  NULL);
```

In Sinatra app , I declared class.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base end
```

For debugging purpose , I wrote this code and run.

```
get "/l" do

  # New comment and set initial value.
  y={:yourname =>"3",:comment =>"commenttest"}

  com = Comment.new(y)
  p com.attribute_names()
  p com

  # New items and set initial value.
  kensaku = {:type=>"000"}
  k = Item.new(kensaku)

  p k.attribute_names()
  p k

  k.type="555"
  p k

end
```

So now I found very interesting things on console.
Comment class succeeded to new with initial value.
But Item class succeeded to new but it is not set initial value.
I wonder why it happens ?

```
#-- Comment class 
["postid", "id", "comment", "created_at", "yourname"]
#<Comment id: nil, comment: "commenttest", yourname: 3, postid: nil, created_at: nil>

#-- Item class 
["type", "postid", "id", "keyword", "created_at"]
#<Item id: nil, type: nil, keyword: nil, postid: nil, created_at: nil>
#<Item id: nil, type: "555", keyword: nil, postid: nil, created_at: nil>
```

Comment: Try to change the name of the `type` attribute

Comment: Oh,my goodness... Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The column name `type` is a [reserved word](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions) in ActiveRecord:

> While these column names are optional, they are in fact reserved by
>   Active Record. **Steer clear of reserved keywords** unless you want the
>   extra functionality. **For example, `type` is a reserved keyword** used to
>   designate a table using Single Table Inheritance (STI). If you are not
>   using STI, try an analogous keyword like "context", that may still
>   accurately describe the data you are modeling.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. But this is a check that is made (or not made) by the software (namely ActiveRecord). You can open a feature request if you like, and maybe they'll add this check in future versions